# After Yosemite upgrade, cannot download new tools from Android SDK manager

Tags: homebrew, android-sdk-tools, osx-yosemite

So, it fails with the error:

> File not found: /temp

This is happening after upgrading the Mac OS to Yosemite and only if you have installed Android SDK via `homebrew`

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$ANDROID_HOME/temp` file exists and symlinks to a location which is owned by thr `root` user.
Deleting this symlink worked for me.